# How can I remove an autoupdate on sqlalchemy Column?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

When updating two other column values, the created column, which remains untouched on my code, updates to the current time by itself.

This is the Model

```
class Query(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "query"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(2000))
    created = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    modified = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    launched = db.Column(db.Integer)
    exception = db.Column(db.String(500), nullable=True)
    enable = db.Column(db.Boolean)
    expired = db.Column(db.Boolean)
    app_id = db.Column(db.String(20))
    app_secret = db.Column(db.String(40))
    page_id = db.Column(db.String(20))
    token = db.Column(db.String(300))
```

updating code

```
query.launched = query.launched + 1
query.modified = until
db.session.commit()
```

What I expected is the modified column to be updated to the 'until' time, which already happens, but the created column to stay untouched.

Comment: With some more testing, I ended up seeing that it does not happen in my local machine. While connected to an external database with mysql+pymysql this error happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the error. It was in my sql syntax. I still didn't figure out why did it happen, but it was resolved by changing this:

-`created` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL

+`created` TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP